# Functional equation of $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Suppose the function $f(n)$ is given by:
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$
Where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I am looking for a formula that enables me to express $f(n)$ as :

$$f(n)=\sum a_{n,k}f(k)\;\;\;\;;\;\;k\in \mathbb{Z}\;\;\;\;\;\;a_{k}\in \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: $a_n=1$, $a_k=0$ whenever $k\ne n$. Would that not work?

Comment: By the way, what led you to think of this particular representation of $f(n)$? It seems at first glance that the most important feature of $f(n)$ is that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}=\int_x^{x+\pi} g(x)\,dx.$

Comment: $a_{n}=1$ would definitely work, but i am looking for a nontrivial formula !

Comment: If (as I presume) the coefficients $a_k$ are not constant (i.e. dependent on the value of $n$ in $f(n)$ on the LHS), there are innumerable ways of assigning values to them.

Comment: lets take an example : $f(1)=g(x)$, $f(2)=g(x)+g\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Obviously, you can't write $f(2)=a_{2,1}f(1)$, where $a_{2,1}$ doesn't depend on $x$ ! you might need to consider higher values of $k$. But what is the form of combination !! my gut feeling says it's gotta be a number-theoretic formula !